# one issue with make[3.82] for Android source code build

Tags: android, makefile

I am using Ubuntu(15.04) environment to build the android source code. For the android K version, it needs the Make version as 3.81 or 3.82, and I used the 3.82 version as below:

```
liny@liny:~/mine/$ make --version
GNU Make 3.82
Built for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 2010  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

But I got two build error caused by Make seems doesn't support some feature such as '-=' or the define feature, could anybody help check it and tell me how make can support these function? Thanks a lot for your help.

**Scenario 1:
Makefile:**

```
116 ifeq ($(LLVM_VER_31), 1)
117 LLVM_LLC_SOURCES -= \
118         $(LLVM_OXILIASMPRINTER_SRCS)
119 endif
```

**Error**:
sc/sc.srcs.mk:117: *** missing separator.  Stop.

**Scenario 2:
Makefile:**

```
12 libmmipl_cflags := -g -O3 \
13         $(CPU)
14         -Dlrintf=_ffix_r \
15         -D__alignx\(x\)=__attribute__\(\(__aligned__\(x\)\)\)
16         -D_POSIX_SOURCE \
17         -DPOSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L \
```

**Error**:
ipl/Android.mk:16: *** recipe commences before first target.  Stop.

Comment: What is it that you expect `-=` to do, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Your second problem is that line 15 is missing a <kbd>\</kbd> at the end, so line 16 looks like the start of a new logical line. Since it starts with a tab, `make` thinks it's an out-of-place recipe.

For your first problem, neither make v3.81 nor the latest v4.1 understand `-=` as an assignment operator.